# React Styling with SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am digging a npm project, that project use `.scss` file for styling.

It imports style like below:

`import styles from './node-content-renderer.scss'`

and use it like an object to component's classname.

```
 <button
      type="button"
      className={styles.collapseButton}
 >
```

How does it can use `styles` like above? When I try that in my local environment, the `styles` is just `{}` (empty object). Even I install `node-sass` to my project.

The exist code link is : https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/blob/master/node-content-renderer.js

It use `scss` file like js object. How can I do that in my project? Should I set up some webpack config? Is there a any easier way that not disrupt my `create-react-app` based project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available for `react-scripts` above 2.0. You should follow the pattern from documentation: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet